# TinyMCE not capturing spacebar/whitespace keypress

Tags: firefox, tinymce, whitespace, space

I ran into a strange issue with tinyMCE that i was not able to replicate outside of my complete framework. The whole thing runs only in FireFox, as it supports only FF, therefore the issue is limited to FF.

I use AJAX calls to dynamically load one or multiple instances of tinyMCE.

However, when entering/editing text the spacebar will not work in the text editor. All other keys work, but the spacebar does not. Instead it triggers a page jump in the browser window itself.

This issue only occurs on Windows under FF 12.0

It all works perfectly fine on FF under OSX.

I was unable to find out why this would be happening. Perhaps somebody can give constructive input. Thank You!

Comment: sounds wierd, but might be that a javascript error is causing a page jump. do you get any js errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a bug in TinyMCEs input handling and occurs in some cases when TinyMCE is being introduced to a document dynamically.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  I am running into the exact same problem in 2017.